# How to find the limit $ \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2-1} \right) $

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2-1} \right)
$$

I have tried rationalizing but that just introduces a extra denominator.
I have tried squaring and rooting but that give me $\lim_{ x \to \infty} \sqrt{x}$ which is not the answer.

Comment: That denominator creates a $\infty/\infty$ form, which is easy to evaluate.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056840/solving-lim-x-to-infty-sqrtx2x1-sqrt1-xx2-using-o-littl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, we first proceed by rationalising:

$$\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2 - 1} = \frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+\sqrt{x^2 - 1} }$$

Now divide by $x$ and apply limit $x \to \infty$.

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1+\frac{2}{x}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}+\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{x^2}} }$$

You will see the limit is $1/2$

Answer (score 2):

You can use binomial approximation $$(1+a)^b \approx 1+ba$$ for $a \to 0$.

This will give you (at $x \to \infty$)$$ \sqrt{x^2+x+1} = x\left(\sqrt{ 1+\underbrace{\frac 1x+ \frac1{x^2}}_{\to 0}}\right) \approx x\left(1+\frac1{2x}+\frac{1}{2x^2} \right)$$

And $$\sqrt{x^2-1}=x\left( \sqrt{1\underbrace{-\frac{1}{x^2}}_{\to 0}}\right) \approx x\left(1-\frac1{2x^2}\right)$$

Thus $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2-1} \right)= \lim_{x \to \infty} x\left(1+\frac1{2x}+\frac{1}{2x^2} \right)- x\left(1-\frac1{2x^2}\right)=\frac 12$$

Comment: Stupid, revenge downvote.

Comment: Your answer is actually quite good and thought out - (+1) to you!

Comment: I sincerely hate those who don't give justification of their down vote and more importantly on a post which is good enough to be upvoted. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Not only $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt x$ is not  *the* answer, but it's not even *an* answer: a limit when $x$ tends to some value is a *number*, and cannot depend on $x$.

You can indeed rationalise, and use some equivalents for the denominator:
$$\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2-1}=\frac{x^2+x+1-(x^2-1)}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$
Now $x+2\sim_\infty x$ and $\sqrt{x^2+x+1},\sqrt{x^2-1}\sim_\infty |x|$, so 
$$\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2-1}\sim_\infty \frac x{2|x|}\to\begin{cases}\phantom{-}\dfrac12&\text{if }x\to+\infty,\\[1ex]- \dfrac12&\text{if }x\to -\infty.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2-1} \right) = 
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\left(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2-1} \right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+x+1}+\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)}{
 \sqrt{x^2+x+1}+\sqrt{x^2-1} 
}
$$

$$= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x² + x +1 - x² +1}{
 \sqrt{x^2+x+1}+\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

$$= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ x +2}{
 \sqrt{x^2+x+1}+\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

$$= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ x +2}{
 \sqrt{x²(1+1/x+1/x²)}+\sqrt{x^2(1-1/x²)}}$$

$$= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ x(1 +2/x)}{
 x\sqrt{1+1/x+1/x²}+x\sqrt{1-1/x²}}$$

$$= \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ 1+2/x}{
 \sqrt{1+1/x+1/x²}+\sqrt{1-1/x²}} = \frac{1}{1+1} = \frac{1}{2}$$